# Java implementation of Merge Sort for Linked List splitting issue

Tags: java, linked-list, mergesort

I've been looking at merge sort implementation in Java and don't understand the following part:

```
Node middle = getMiddle(head);      //get the middle of the list
Node left_head = head;
Node right_head = middle.next; 
middle.next = null;             //split the list into two half's
```

So by setting **middle.next = null** we split **left_head** by the middle. But why **right_head** remains in place since it refers to **middle.next** which became **null**?

UPDATE: Ok, so what got me confused here is that `middle.next = null` doesn't actually sets next Node as a null, but updates `middle's` *next* variable to **null**, which of course doesn't affect `right_head`.

Comment: Note a [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) avoids the recursive scanning and splitting of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully observe the code segment you've posted, you'll see that the code executes line by line in this case. Following is a step by step description :

1) `middle` is set to point to the middle most node.
2) `left head` points to the first node in the left part of the split.
3) `right head` points to the first node in the right part of the split, which is actually the next to the middle node.
4) when `middle.next` is set to null, the chaining of nodes is broken and the linked list splits into two halves, where `left_head` and `right_head`, point to the corresponding left and right segments.

Answer (score 0):

`right_head` was set *before* `middle.next` became null. So it holds the value of whatever was set before it becomes null.

You did not post the entire code segment, so I cannot confirm with certainty, but given `merge sort`'s desire to split the array into two pieces, sort them, and then combine them, it probably will reselect the `middle` element to which it should sort around for the next go, which is why it resets after this one.